# how to modify request to get_template_part()?

Tags: customization, get-template-part, theme-p2

i am modifying a P2 theme for a specific purpose, and it uses the `get_template_part( 'entry' )` function to get the the whole entry html.

What i then get is the who `<li>` element, but i want to be able to move things around [putting meta at the end of the post, for example].  but codex has no documentation for it [that i could find].   does this mean i have to use my own entry-getting method, or making a new loop?    i hope not because P2 is so well sorted.

thanks a bunch for any tip!

adir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked in the P2 theme files. The theme loads the `entry.php` with the function `p2_load_entry()` located in `inc/template-tags.php`.

If you want to edit the `entry.php` file and want to be on the safe side if P2 releases an update, you should create a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

1. Create a new sub-folder inside `wp-content/themes/` e.g. `p2-child`
2. Inside the new folder, create a `style.css` with the content described in the above linked article. Be sure that you have added `Template: p2` to the comment block.
3. Copy `entry.php` to the new folder and edit it.
4. Go to WordPress Admin `Appearance > Themes` and activate your newly created P2 Child Theme.

Comment: thanks Roman!  i had actually already been to that file; dont know why i didnt remember that..    are there any objections to making a totally new theme from this one, and just renaming it and documenting that its derived from it?  i dont actually want the P2 updates..

Comment: No, you don't have to create a child theme. But the benefits are worth the 5minutes of work here ;). Btw. `get_template_part()` is just a better `include()`. If you want to create a modified `entry.php` just copy the file, rename it (e.g. `entry-myedits.php`) and set the include to `get_template_part('entry', 'myedits');` in `p2_load_entry()`.

Comment: what kind of benefits would you mention? just future development compatibility and such?  [not that im saying its not worth it, but im just wondering if there's more to it]  THANKS!

Comment: Yes, just for the future. For example: I had a customer last month whose site was hacked (timthumb bug). Because the files where edited by a script, I had to re-download and re-install everything from scratch. The customer had made some changes to the theme before and I had to figure out which file was different from the original theme, checked the file for some nasty evil scriptcode and moved the diff to the new file. If I had a child-theme to work with, the required time would be halved.

Comment: mm i wanted to PM you but i guess i cant.   well sorry you had to go through that, i hope ill learn from that and not wait for it to happen to me as well.... =]   cheers